# How to add icons to AngularUI calendar

Tags: angularjs, calendar, angular-ui, glyphicons

I used this [AngularUI calendar](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar)

I want to add icons (Bootstrap glyphicons) like this

[image]

any help please,

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.With `className` Event Object you can do this.

```
$scope.events = [
    {className: 'fa fa-bar-chart', title: 'dashboard', start: new Date(y, m, 1), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance'},
    {className: 'fa fa-user', title: 'dashboard 2', start: new Date(y, m, 1), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/d/dash2'},
    {className: 'fa fa-bar-chart', title: 'invoice', start: new Date(y, m, 5), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/invoice/invoice#!/invoice_view'},
    {id: 999, title: 'documents', start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/files/browse/home'},
    {id: 999, title: 'control side', start: new Date(y, m, d + 4, 16, 0), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/manage/dashboard'},
    {title: 'balance', start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0), end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/d/balance'},
    {title: 'invoice settings', start: new Date(y, m, 28), end: new Date(y, m, 29), url: 'http://localhost/view_finance/invoice/invoice#!/invoice_setting'}
];
```